# Serialize and deserialize objects and properties in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem with the serialization and deserialization of objects in Java, and I think it's because I do not really understand how it works. My program consists of some spreadsheets as in Excel, but by console. I have a class "Book" and a class "Page". In Book, I have declared a Page's HashMap and in Page I have a String's Hashmap (to simulate the cells). Now I want that book to be persistent and for that what I do is serialize the "libro" object (Book instance):

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOut =
    new FileOutputStream("H:\\Users\\thero\\Desktop\\bin\\libro.bin");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    out.writeObject(libro);
    out.close();
    fileOut.close();
    System.out.printf("Se ha guardado el libro correctamente");
} 
catch (IOException i) {
    i.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code is included in a method of a class called "Salvar" that I call from the main. At the same time I have a class "Cargar" with the opposite method:

```
    try {
     FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("H:\\Users\\thero\\Desktop\\bin\\libro.bin");
     ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
     libro = (Book) in.readObject();
     in.close();
     fileIn.close();
  } catch (IOException i) {
     i.printStackTrace();

  } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Cargar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I also call this method from the main, and when executing it, no exception jumps. However, it seems that it only loads the Book instance, but it does not load the Hashmap property, and therefore it does not load the created spreadsheets with the cells. Where is the problem? This is my class Book code:

```
    package javacalc.items;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class Book implements Serializable{
    private HashMap<String, Page> libro;
    private Page activePage;
    private String nameActivePage;

    public Book(){
        this.libro = new HashMap<>();
    }
    public List <String> getListPages() {
        ArrayList <String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s: this.libro.keySet())
            myList.add(s);
        return myList;
    }

    public void setListPages(String s, Page p) {
        this.libro.put(s,p);
    }

    public void deletePage(String s){
        this.libro.remove(s);
    }

    public Page getActivePage() {
        return activePage;
    } 

    public boolean setActivePage(String activePage) {
        Page p = this.libro.get(activePage);
        this.nameActivePage = activePage;
        this.activePage = p;
        return true;
    }

    public String getNameActivePage(){
        return nameActivePage;
    }

    public boolean containsPage(String s){
        return libro.containsKey(s);
    }

    public HashMap<String, Page> getLibro() {
        return this.libro;
    }

}
```

Thank you.

---

Okey I think I resolved correctly I just made some changes in "Cargar":

```
try {
         String ruta = comando.substring(8, comando.length()-1).trim();
         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(ruta);
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
         Book libro_c = (Book) in.readObject();
         libro.setLibro(libro_c.getLibro());
         in.close();
         fileIn.close();
```

Now it works! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: It looks like it does. Are you expecting a `HashMap` you have already retrieved with `getLibro` to  also be updated?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Exactly, what I want is to get the HashMap updated when I load the file, so I can see the spreadsheets and the contents of the cells exactly as when I saved the book.

Comment: So call `getLibro` on the new object.

Comment: @theroxd4n would you please add a short test case that demonstrates that it is not working as expected?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline If I change this line:  `libro = (Book) in.readObject();` to this `libro.getBook() = (HashMap<String, Page>) in.readObject();` Netbeans show me: unexpected type required: variable found: value.

Comment: @theroxd4n I'm not surprised. But where you are using the `HashMap` will need to be update with the new one.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. libro is an instance of Book and getBook() returns libro(same name as the object but this is a HashMap). I don't load the file in a new object and then modify the pointer of the previous object to the new one, I load the content of the file in the same instance of Book (libro), so I think I don't have to update anything again.

Comment: Is your Page object serializable ?

Comment: @uncleBounty Yes, it implements Serializable.